# Issue Comparing Dates in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's the run down of the whole setup.
What I am trying to achieve here is that, for every entry in TradeTable T1, I am fetching swing price based on T1.Ticker which is S.SymbolDb in SwingTable S. and the S.closetime in swing table for that swing value of SymbolDb should be earlier than the entry time T.timestamp . but the result has timeclose later than that of entry as highlighted in the pic below.

Looking at each table hints that time formats are different in both tables but in the query I am casting them to same type and then comparing. Any suggestions on what I missed here.

**QueryResult**

[image]

**TradeCall Table**

[image]

**SwingTable**

[image]

```
 SELECT
    T3.*,
    DerivedTable.swings,DerivedTable.swing_price,DerivedTable.time_close
FROM TradeCall T3
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        T2.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.SymbolDb ORDER BY T2.time_close DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM SwingTable T2, TradeCall T1
    WHERE datetime(T2.time_close) < datetime(T1.TimeStamp)
    AND T2.swings IS NOT NULL AND 
    CASE WHEN T1.Position = 'LONG' THEN 
        T2.swing_price < T2.price_close 
    ELSE
        T2.swing_price > T2.price_close 
    END
) DerivedTable
ON T3.Ticker = DerivedTable.SymbolDb
WHERE DerivedTable.RowNum = 1;
```

**Using SQLite**

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27?

Comment: Also, please add some queries to your question to create your database and sample data that reproduces the issue you are having. Do not just copy your real world data, but remove any columns and rows that are not important, so you have a proper [mcve]. This will not only help us help you, but may also help you pinpoint the problem yourself if you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting `datetime(T2.time_close)` and `datetime(T1.TimeStamp)` from the inner query to see what the values are being converted to. The "Z" on the end hints that time_close is in Zulu time, whereas timestamp looks like it is in local time.

Using more memorable aliases for the tables, like `FROM SwingTable ST, TradeCall TC` will make the SQL easier to read, understand, and maintain, even if it doesn't fix the problem.